# Why does Python's timeit() execute endlessly?

Tags: python, cpython, timeit

When trying to use the Python built-in module 'timeit' as follows:

```
timeit.Timer('print "hi"').timeit()
```

it prints more than one line; why is that? It keeps printing "hi" endlessly:

```
hi
hi
hi
hi
...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`timeit` is designed to test extremely short code snippets, so it runs the code many times and averages them. As a default, it runs it 1000000 times.

You can change this by running it as follows:

```
timeit.Timer('print "hi"').timeit(number=1)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you look at the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit), you will see that the statement will default to executing 1000000 times.

If you only want to run it 2 times, you would pass a 2 to the `timeit()` method of the `Timer` class.

```
timeit.Timer('print "hi"').timeit(2)
```